Is it helpful to use a thicker gauge wire for only part of a long circuit run that could have higher loads?
A new circuit is going in to provide 20A power to a residential garage, mainly for power tools, but also for the garage door motor. All of that and a couple of overhead lights are currently drawing off a 15A circuit that powers various other rooms in this house (a DIY'd home from 1960, where circuits are based more on efficient wire paths than separating uses).
This new circuit will be pretty long, 75-100 ft, going from one end of this ranch house with the panel to the opposite end where the semi-attached garage is. The goal is to have a safer circuit for higher loads and reduce/separate those higher loads from the garage lighting circuit and other stuff on the 15A circuit around the house.
Given the new circuit is almost 100ft long and could be used with high loads (power tools, battery chargers, trickle charging EVs in the future), it made sense to me that the 50 ft stretch of cable from the panel to garage could be a thicker gauge to reduce resistance / voltage drop / heat buildup on wires. For example, running 10/2 from the panel to the edge of the basement wall (where the garage begins), then splicing in 12/2 to go from basement to garage, then wrap 12/2 in conduit around garage for 20A garage receptacles. A local hardware store had a nice sale, so I went ahead and got 50 ft of 10/2 for this reason.
An electrician said that using 10/2 is technically fine, but it's unnecessary / overkill. Is using 10/2 actually helpful in terms of improving circuit safety and performance, or would it contribute nothing (compared to 12/2)? I realize it's helpful to minimize splices for safety (possible loose connections) and voltage drop reasons, but going from basement to garage would likely call for a junction anyway, going from NM along the basement ceiling edge, to conduit in the garage.

It's madness to add electrical circuits to a garage without thinking about EV charging.  Because that is a real thing that IS coming.  I realize there were EV attempts in the 90s and 00s that went nowhere, and a person might say "well it died the last 2 times".  Nope, it's the real deal this time. The X-factors are a) battery tech has arrived, and b) the rest of the world is all-in. America will not be an ICE-only bastion, and enough homebuyers will want to see EV charging capability that it will hurt your resale not to have it.
Your idea of stepping up to #10 isn't wrong, since about 75' will put you over 3% on a 120V circuit simply due to the lower voltage.  I would carry it the whole run rather than have an intermediate splice.  I would also run 10/3+gnd as a MWBC.  But that's besides the point, for wire cost reasons I would do no such thing at all!  I would run the very affordable 2-2-2-4 aluminum (safe at these large sizes) as a feeder to a subpanel.  Subpanels have terminals rated for aluminum (made of aluminum) and #2 provides 90A to the garage, which is all you'll ever need for EV charging multiple cars. Don't listen to those novices who say you need 48A per car, that's nuts.
This fat wire will completely remove any issues with voltage drop.
Then you install your circuit(s) out of the subpanel.
Now I recommend conduit the entire run, and I recommend at least 1-1/4" preferably 1-1/2".  That's to hedge your bets on emerging tech called V2X - Vehicle to Home during outages, Vehicle to Grid if you want to buy up cheap midnight power and flip it back to the utility during peak hours for much more money.   The conduit will also provide a route/way for data cables if you need a Dynamic Load Management system to fit EV charging inside the existing home panel capacity.

Thanks for the thoughtful input. This is getting a little off topic but I want to keep digging into it - before seeing your reply this morning, I planned to start a new Q, but you already responded to what that new Q would be. Basically I was wondering about running 12/3 from main panel to garage, and have that provide 20A 240V to one receptacle (for an EV) and 120V to the rest. Your suggestion is much more 'future proofing' and aligned with @jay613's idea.

For the main panel replacement planned separately, we were going the larger SquareD Q0 54-circuit panel to avoid running out of space. If adding a subpanel on this opposite end of the house makes sense (over by kitchen and garage), then maybe we can sip such a large panel and get a tamer sized Q0 main panel. Or if the price diff isn't much, doesn't hurt to have many spaces in the main and a nice subpanel.

Looking back at my electrician's reasoning on getting us more circuit spaces by upgrading main panel vs a subpanel, for one it was because the service and panel is showing serious signs of wear anyway, but here's what else they said. Does that make sense to you, or you still think a subpanel is worthwhile 50ft on the other end of this ranch house basement? I don't have an EV yet but want to replace a car with one, and 20A 240V would be plenty charging for now.

"IMO,  if you do the main service and new 200 amp 54 circuit main electrical panel now with interlock and alarm for the generator you will have 1 big new panel and generator hook up for the whole house.  Any new wires will fit in that panel from the car charger, basement, range, etc...1 big panel and generator.  Yes, you will need to run wires from that location, however, that is what 90% of the population does due to having only 1 main electrical panel."

@Huesmann yes that's the plan, have a receptacle for 20A 120V and eventually an EV dedicated receptacle at the edge of the garage interior by the garage door, so the 20ft+ charge cable can go from the EVSE indoors to the car outside.

"The X-factors are a) battery tech has arrived, and b) the rest of the world is all-in." You may implicitly understand this but c) an ICE engine has roughly 10 times the number of parts as an electric motor and is much less efficient. The idea that the US is going to keep running ICEs to 'save jobs' because they are so much harder to make is about as ridiculous as arguing that the US would stick to horses and buggies early in the last century.

@cr0 yeah multiple subpanels > one monster panel, You're replacing a bunch of long Romex home-runs with one big aluminum feeder, cheaper and greatly improving voltage drop too, since you rarely load that many 120V circuits at once.  Electricians are shameless about wanting to do whole, in-place panel replacements because it's an obscenely lucrative job, almost 100% labor/profit.  It's often NOT right for the consumer.

@Huesmann a 20A MWBC could support 240V sockets in multiple locations.  Yeah, they're still struggling with the spontaneous ignition issue on ICEs, just nobody talks about THAT.

@Harper-ReinstateMonica in any case we need a panel and service replacement, due to age and corrosion. Thus adding more spaces while we do it

For a 100' run, the voltage drop will be negligible no matter the wire size - I'd have done it with one piece, but that would be just my preference.  10/2 would let you go up to 30A of current, but you're still limited to the minimum capacity of the circuit overall, so if you have any 12 or 14 gauge wire, that's the max you can have for your breaker (20/15A, depending on minimum gauge).  10/2 won't really get you anything above what 12/2 would do for standard outlets since you can't have standard 120V outlets on anything more than a 20A circuit anyway.
If it were me, I'd have, at least, run it as a /3 wire which would have given a lot more options for 240V expansion in the future, even if not currently set up that way. Trying to save a bit of money now on relatively cheap wire may come back to bite you later if you could have planned for future additional needs rather than just what you currently anticipate needing, especially if you're thinking of being able to charge an EV in some manner.

The #10 wire will give you nothing.  On the first fifty feet at full 20A load  you'll see a 1.8% voltage drop instead of 2.8% with #12.   Plus whatever you lose on the rest of the run ... it's nothing.
It's also harder to pull when installing and you'll have a useless junction box just inside the house.
Judging by prices at a large orange retailer today, that #10 wire is a HUGE waste of money.  I hope you bought a whole 50ft package and can return it!  I agree with @Milwrdfan, run 12/3 and put in a pair of handle-tied breakers.  This will be a LOT more useful.
Thinking about capacity: "power tools and the door motor".   Most large power tools use 12 or 13A.  They are designed that way in order to be powerful while functioning on a 15A breaker.  A new DC garage motor uses about 4A, an older one 10 to 12.    So ... if you only have a new DC door motor and a modest tool collection, one circuit will be fine.  If you have an old door motor, you're already overloaded, even with a new 20A circuit.  If you add ANYTHING else ... a heater (so you can work in the garage in winter), a large standup/box fan (so you can work in the garage in summer or evacuate toxic fumes from welding/grinding/painting), a vacuum, any tool with a motor that will cause a large startup current surge, a small slow EV charger, a new set of fast chargers for a new brand of power tools, or if you have two people using two tools at once .... 20A is not enough.
Now is your chance.  Run a 12/3.  Put the door and most outlets on one circuit, and put 2 or 3 clearly marked outlets on the other one for high-powered equipment.  Where the two circuits diverge you'll have 240V@20A if you ever need that.

Thanks for this. I do think I can return the 10/2 and it sounds like whatever I do here, I might as well return that.
Garage door opener is installed in last few years, seems like it's rated for 6A current.

If running 12/3 the whole way, could that be used for a 20A 240V receptacle for EV slow charging, and also for 20A 120V receptacles for the garage door and power tools?

@cr0 it could.  I'm not sure if hard-wiring a 20A EV charger on a circuit with other outlets is allowed, but you could certainly do it with a plug-in one.  In OP's case it would be a terrible idea to plan it that way because the charger would have to be capped at maybe 12A.  You could say "No vacuuming the garage at night" but you have to leave enough for the door, lights, tool chargers, etc.

I was thinking of plug-in EV chargers anyway, since that's more flexible. But I get your point: better to have a dedicated EV circuit if that's a planned use. With that in mind, benefit of 12/3 is that the EV charger could at least have a dedicated 20A 120V on one receptacle, while vacuum and tools etc. could be on the other wire's 20A 120V.

Starting the circuit run from the panel with the 10 AWG wire could be misconstrued in the future as being a circuit capable of handling the current capacity of 10 AWG. It would be very important to mark such circuit that reduced down to 12 AWG somewhere downstream as limited to the capacity of that smaller diameter wire. This would be best done in the panel at the start of the circuit and make sure that the proper 20A circuit breaker is used.

Labeling is OK if it makes you feel better, but it is not an NEC requirement. Breakers must never be upsized based on the end of the wire in the panel, but only after a thorough inspection of the entire circuit.

@nobody - I never suggested it was a requirement. However, with all the DIY activity that gets discussed here and the types of some questions we see it would be obvious that the wire marking I suggest at the panel is a good idea. So please relax some on your strident comment.

@nobody: By what practical means could anyone ever be certain that they've done a thorough inspection of an entire circuit?  I would think there should be a standard means of indicating information about what junction boxes are on what circuits, but I've never seen such things done except in an after-the-fact diagram drawn based on experimentation.

The key point here is when the next DIYer sees 10 AWG wire and puts a bigger breaker on it, they just created a fire hazard at the 12 AWG wire.  Sure, one can say that 'they should have inspected'.  How would they know that at the time?  Especially if they are a new DIYer, and 'inspecting' involves pulling wires out of, or putting inspection holes into, the walls and ceiling.

While in true voltage drop situations (> 200 feet), using larger wire for most of the run and smaller wire for the ends can help a lot, with a short run voltage drop just isn't a real concern. If voltage drop isn't a concern then neither is excess heating as long as you stick to the rated minimums - e.g., 12 AWG for 20A, 10 AWG for 30A.
So really the question becomes: How do I plan for future use by spending a little bit now to save a lot of time/money/hassle later?
There are a few options. A key is that most options require multiple circuits, which means at a minimum a multi-wire branch circuit and very possibly a true subpanel. Either of those requires 3 wires (plus ground). 12/3 will get you 2 x 20A 120V circuits or 1 x 20A 240V circuit. 10/3 will get you 2 x 30A (or downgrade to 20A, that's OK) 120V circuits or 1 x 30A 240V circuit.
But to really get more you need a subpanel. If you go up just one more size to 8 AWG 3-wires then you get 40A @ 240V. Which by using a subpanel gives you 2 x 20A x 120V (one for tools, one for lights and garage door opener, or whatever) and 1 x 20A x 240V which gives you reasonable baseline EV charging.
And once you are in subpanel mode, if you increase wire size and switch to aluminum then you can do a lot more, dependent primarily on how much power you can get from your main panel, which depends on your utility feed and a proper Load Calculation. The typical recommended cable is 2/2/2/4 aluminum - that's 2 AWG for hots and neutral, 4 AWG for ground. That actually compares well in cost (but varies of course by vendor) with 8/3 copper (the /3 really including a 4th wire as ground as well). Which means that for around the same cost as a 40A max. subpanel feed you can actually set things up for 90A, with the actual capacity depending on the amount you can feed from your main panel based on a Load Calculation.
The other alternative is to run conduit large enough for larger and/or more wires in the future. I suspect in this case that simply running cable will be easier, so run cable that has room for the future.
A subpanel costs very little. In fact, a "main panel", but configured as a subpanel (ground and neutral separate is the main thing) doesn't cost much. A quick search finds an Eaton BR 100A panel with some extra breakers included, 20 spaces/"40 circuits", for less than $100. A subpanel in the same building doesn't need a disconnect, but it can be handy, and a "main" panel main breaker works as a disconnect when used as a subpanel but can be larger than the panel feed (so 100A breaker in subpanel with a 30A or 90A or anything in between feed is just fine).

Thanks for breaking this down in detail. As a separate project, I'm about to replace the main panel and service since it is 60 years old, full at 40 slots (all electric house) and showing signs of corrosion. Given that cost, and feeling pretty confident in the garage needing a finite number of circuits (what's listed above and maybe a dedicated 240V EV charger in the future), I figured I'd just do a 20A run now and can do a higher powered EV circuit later. Seems like it comes down to cost of subpanel setup, vs. cost of the 50ft 20A run and 50ft of whatever the EV run would be

Seeing posts like this about EV charging, it seems like installing thick conduit from panel to garage in one big run might be the best option, then run 12/3 through that. Does that sound right to you, or is the subpanel still appealing?

I have a 200A service and am pretty energy efficient, though the whole house runs on electric (with wood heat in winter). I don't have a load calculation done but have done back of the envelope looks at what appliances are drawing.

In an unfinished basement there's not a lot of benefit to running conduit to future-proof against unknown and unplanned upgrades.  The NM cable run as far as the garage is $100 and a couple hours.  Don't get scope creep for nothing.  If you are ripping open a ceiling to do this work, absolutely run a conduit.  Where is the kitchen?   If it's on the garage side of the house, a subpanel opposite the garage wall and underneath the kitchen would be a good move as part of a panel upgrade.

Basement has exposed joists overhead, no ceiling. Lots of NM stapled to edge of ceiling by the wall, though electrician says what they install would need to be through holes in joists. Kitchen is opposite end of house from panel, sharing the same far wall as the garage.

I got a quote on a subpanel months ago because I was adding a room and 3 circuits to the basement, and the panel+service replacement was more necessary and not a whole lot more expensive surprisingly. So those 3 circuits are already run to the panel. Feels like a shame to get a subpanel too after all that! But I am interested in "future proofing" to reasonable extent and don't want to decide based on sunk costs. So it comes back to my earlier Q in this comment thread: cost of subpanel setup vs. cost of the 50ft 20A run and 50ft of whatever the EV charger run would be someday

Has your kitchen ever had a major electrical upgrade?   If not  it's a good plan to install a 100A or even 200A subpanel under the kitchen against the garage wall, and an appropriate aluminum service wire back to the main panel.  Whatever that costs.   From there you upgrade kitchen circuits as and when needed from underneath the kitchen walls.  And you power the garage from it.  It's all very short runs now.  IDK what you have but with an EV and electric range and dryer in the kitchen, this panel may represent the bulk of your usage even though it's a "sub".

Ask your electrician ... maybe what you'll do is new main panel OUTSIDE, new large subpanel where I suggest, and your existing panel is replaced with a smaller subpanel fed from the outside one.   Whichever way you go, a large panel near the kitchen and garage can be installed NOW as a sub from your existing main, and end up part of the master plan.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

You haven't said where you are (US or Canada), so I'll answer you both ways.
Under the National Electrical Code (NEC) in the USA (NFPA 70) and the Canadian Electrical Code (CEC) in Canada (CSA C22.1), 120 V 15 A circuits are not permitted to have a voltage drop of more than 5% when under full load. A general rule is that a circuit should never be intentionally loaded to over 80% of the nominal full load. So:
15 A x 0.8 = 12 A
120 V x 0.05 = 6 V drop = 114 V minimum on the circuit at 12 A
120 V x 12 A = 1440 VA
1440/114 = 12.6 A, rounding up to 13 A (still within the nominal rating of the breaker.)
120 V/12 A = 10 Ω circuit impedance (load + conductor resistance)
114 V/13 A = 8.8 Ω circuit impedance (load + conductor resistance)
14 AWG wire has 2.58 Ω/km at 77 ºF (25 ºC) and 2.97 Ω/km at 149 ºF (65 ºC), which matters as the hottest a wire should ever run is in that range. NMD 7 cable (the typical 14/2 or 14/3 cable used in home construction) has a temperature rating of 90 °C. If you compare the two resistances, you will note that copper wire has a positive temperature coefficient of resistance, meaning that as the temperature increases, so does the resistance.
2.97 Ω/km = 0.000905255971 Ω/foot, so 100' of 14/2 cable is going to have 2 x (0.000905255971 x 100) = 0.0905255971 Ω.
0.0905255971 Ω x 15 A (nominal max) = 1.4 V drop which is << 6 V drop allowed. At 77 ºF (25 ºC), the drop will be less, of course.
[1] https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/copper-wire-d_1429.html

Voltage drop is generally only an enforceable rule in the CEC -- the NEC's talk of voltage drop for branch circuits is in an informational note, not enforceable text, save for fire pumps and a few other very rare circumstances

Yup, that is correct. However, the engineering principals I illustrated are still valid, even if the 5% voltage drop isn't enforceable in the US.
